# Publishing ios app through virtual mac

Tags: ios, app-store

I am using macincloud for creating my ios app. I am almost done creating it and now want to publish it to the app store. I have tested the app on test flight via internal testers. My application has support for remote notification via.

Now my question is what steps i should follow to publish the app so that everything works if tomorrow i use another computer to publish an update. While signing the application i remember i had to export a key from the keychain app. So i am guessing i will need to export certain things. So just to be sure, can someone tell me what all i need to export and backup so that my application doesn't break if something happens on the macincloud machine.

PS: macincloud machines are reusable and in their terms they explicitly mentioned that once my subscription is over they will wipe everything on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This question really has nothing to do with a virtual Mac. The question would apply to switching development to any new computer.

Technically you don't need anything except a good backup of your code.

Ideally you should keep a backup of your development and distribution certificates so they can be installed on a new machine. This allows you to keep using all of your existing provisioning profiles.

But it's not required. You can create new certificates for the new machine and then update all of your provisioning profiles to use the new certificate. Not really a big deal. This process needs to be done once a year anyway even if you still have the same machine.

None of this affects your ability to publish your app update. That only depends on the app's Bundle Id.